# MINUS functionality in BigQuery database

Tags: google-bigquery

I am new to **BigQuery** database.

Like in Oracle database **MINUS** operator what is the same functionality in BigQuery? I did not find MINUS operator in BigQuery.

Oracle --> Minus
BigQuery --> ??

Answer (score 7):

Though there is no MINUS function in BigQuery, you can use a LEFT OUTER JOIN as an alternative.

```
 SELECT name, uid FROM a
 MINUS
 SELECT name, uid FROM b
```

Can be written as:

```
SELECT a.name, a.uid
FROM a LEFT OUTER JOIN b ON a.name= b.name AND a.uid= b.uid
WHERE b.name IS NULL
```

Comment: it seems to me that 'IS NULL' was correct?  you add matching B parts to A, so where there is no match, B vals will be NULL and that are the records that would also result from the MINUS..?

Comment: I still cannot fathom why MINUS isn't in BigQuery.

Comment: EXCEPT DISTINCT is better for MINUS functionality, you don't need to generate ON clause for all the columns.

Answer (score 6):

BigQuery doesn't have "MINUS", but it does have the functionally identical "[EXCEPT DISTINCT](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#except)".

Answer (score 5):

```
with whole as
( select 1 as id, 'One' as value
  union all
  select 2 as id, 'Two' as value
  union all
  select 3 as id, 'Three' as value
  ),
  sub_set as
  (
   select 1 as id, 'One' as value
  union all
  select 2 as id, 'Two' as value
  )
  select * from whole
  except distinct
  select * from sub_set
```

Result was

```
    3 Three
```

Refer: https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/query-syntax#except

I am getting the error EXCEPT ALL is not supported, DISTINCT worked. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

StandardSQL Output for MINUS where ID is the composite key or primary key in Table 1 and Table2

> same concept as Vamsi Mohan's

```
Select ID, Name from Table 1
where ID not in (Select distinct ID in Table 2)
```